# laptop ram upgrade on shared memory

Tags: memory, graphics

I own a Samsung np305E5A-AO3IN laptop. It has currently 4x1 4 GB  DDr3 (1333Mhz) RAM. My lap has shared memory. So I would like to upgrade my memory to 6 GB by adding a 2GB module with existing 4GB module.

I was planning to add a graphics RAM but a friend of mine told me that adding a graphics RAM on my specific model is not a good idea as it will cause restarting and such troubles. Can anyone give me a solid advice on this topic?

Should I just upgrade it to 6GB by adding a normal 2 GB with it or can I use 2GB graphics RAM to improve my gaming performance?

Comment: adding RAM doesn't improve gaming performance.

Answer (score 1):

"6 gb by adding a 2gb module with existing 4gb module"

First, there are 4 memory slots.  Each one has 1 GB of RAM.  If you add one two GB memory module you will remove one 1 GB memory module to add the new one.  That will give you 2 GB in one slot and 3 slots of one GB each totaling 5 GB.  In order to get to 6 GB you'll need to insert 2 2GB memory modules (and use two of the 1GB RAM sticks already in the computer).

Second, you can't add "graphics RAM."  Not possible.  You need to add DDR3.  Don't get creative and buy something else.

Comment: There seems to be only 2 slots for memory. Accordong to specs a the shops. http://www.abhiabhi.com/Samsung-NP305E5A-A03IN-Laptop-apu-dual-core-a4-4-gb-750-gb_5051fa0bb83b63574b314ead

Comment: http://compareindia.in.com/specification/laptops/samsung-np305e5aa03in/274382  Yup it does in fact only have 2 memory slots.  I believed the OP when they stated it had 4.  I should have checked, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop has embedded graphics, so you almost certainly can't add "Graphics RAM" - the "Shared Memory" means the memory is shared between the graphics card and the rest of the system.

According to the specs of the device and the Kingston Website you can put add a 2 Gig or 4 gig memory module for a total of 6 or 8 gigs of RAM.

That said, you should double check your configuration - according to the Kingston website the standard configuration for the 4GB model is 2 x 2 gig DIMMS.  If this is the case you will need to remove one of the 2 gig DIMMS and replace it with a 4 gig DIM.

I am not a gamer, but I'd be pretty confident that if you wanted to allocate more of the memory to the GPU in the BIOS, and if the BIOS supports it, it should work OK.